# TPPDF : Add Multiple images with text content in the same cell in the Table()

Tags: swift, pdf-generation, tppdf

I am working on a PDF Builder app and came through [this](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF) tutorial.

Is there any way around to add some text in a cell with multiple images. I tried different ways but it results into error in the PDF.

I have tried this :

```
      let table = PDFTable()
        
            let str = String(format: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
            let str1 = String(format: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n\nIt has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ")
    
            do {
                try table.generateCells(
                    data:[
                        ["Name", "Image", "Description"],
                        [project.name + "\n" +  project.address1, UIImage(named: "demo")!, str],
                        [project.name + "\n" +  project.address1, UIImage(named: "demo")!, str1]
                        ],
                    alignments: [
                    [.topLeft, .top, .top],
                    [.topLeft, .top, .top],
                    [.topLeft, .top, .top]
                        ])
                } catch PDFError.tableContentInvalid(let value) {
                    // In case invalid input is provided, this error will be thrown.

                    print("This type of object is not supported as table content: " + String(describing: (type(of: value))))
                } catch {
                    // General error handling in case something goes wrong.

                    print("Error while creating table: " + error.localizedDescription)
                }
    
    table.widths = [
               0.23, 0.30, 0.47
           ]
    
        let style = PDFTableStyleDefaults.simple
    table.style = style
    
    do {
        // Style each cell individually
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 1, column: 0, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 1, column: 1, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 1, column: 2, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 2, column: 0, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 2, column: 1, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
        try table.setCellStyle(row: 2, column: 2, style: PDFTableCellStyle(colors: (fill: UIColor.lightGray, text: UIColor.black)))
    } catch PDFError.tableIndexOutOfBounds(let index, let length){
        // In case the index is out of bounds

        print("Requested cell is out of bounds! \(index) / \(length)")
    } catch {
        // General error handling in case something goes wrong.

        print("Error while setting cell style: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    table.padding = 1.0
    table.margin = 2.0
    
    table.showHeadersOnEveryPage = true
    
    document.add(table: table)
```

How can I find some way around?

Comment: The author of TPPDF (contactable through the github page) is very responsive and will reply to any query you send him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for not responding earlier (somehow I didn't get notified).

1. Try using a group inside the table cell.
2. Try the new table api & logic (still in development, see branch `develop`), and if this still does not resolve your issue open a new issue. Please provide a code sample project for me to reproduce your use case.